# Volume of unit sphere by iterative integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, volume

I want to calculate the volume of the unit sphere: $\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R} \,|\, x^2+y^2 \leq 1\} = K$

---

I am supposed to use iterative integration. We have defined the volume as:

$\int_\mathbb{R^2}\,\, 1_K \,\,d\lambda^2$

I can write this as an iterative integral:

$\int_a^b \int_c^d \,\,1 \,\,dx_1 dx_2$, where a,b and c,d are the bounds for $K$ so that $(a,c) \leq (x,y) \leq (b,d) \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in K$.

My approach was, for symmetrical reasons, to first write it as $4 \int_0^b \int_0^d \,\,1 \,\,dx_1 dx_2$ and then choose $d = \sqrt{1-b^2}$ but I just can't get to the result that would be correct: $\pi$

---

I tried to search for similar questions and they all used some spherical transformation without explaining what they do exactly. We didn't have spherical transformation yet. We had transformation though, but I don't see how they get these transformation equations and why they can be used.

---

My approach:
$4 \int_0^b \int_0^{\sqrt{1-b^2}} \,\,1 \,\,dx_1 dx_2 = 4 \int_0^b \sqrt{1-b^2} \,\,dx_2 = 4b\sqrt{1-b^2}$

But now I'm not sure how to continue, how to choose $b$. My guess would be $b=1$ but then the result would be $0$.

Comment: "they all used some spherical transformation" Changing coordinates so that the boundaries of the region are simple 
to express is usually extremely worth it. So generally that's a very good idea. Which is why it's so often done.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your idea (except the factor of 2 should be 4). Show us your work.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I have added my work, thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to square a circle and that is never going to work. Plainly, there are no constant $a,b,c,d$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$ and $c \leq y \leq d$ iff $(x, y)$ is the unit circle, because the first region is a rectangle. What you can say is $(x, y)$ is in the unit circle iff $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ and $-\sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x \leq +\sqrt{1-y^2}$. So try using $d = \sqrt{1 - x_2^2}$.

Comment: Okay I got, thank you!